# JavaScript memory leaks causing page not to load?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, loading

I am running a simple game program with JavaScript and Brackets, and I came across a problem about the page not loading. I tried to run the game, and nothing happened, no information got to chrome about what it was running, it just loaded forever. I looked in the console, and I found that there were a bunch of memory leaks, but I haven't found anything about memory leaks causing the page to not load. I found that there was a certain line of code that when deleted let the page load, but it didn't make any sense.

I've google the problem, to which I found nothing.

Here's the line that causes the problem:

```
if (this.y + yOffSet < canvas.height / 6){
    yOffSet += canvas.height / 6 - (this.y + yOffSet);
}
```

**Note:** `yOffSet` is a global variable

Any Idea what might be the problem?

Comment: So by removing this `if()` condition if fixes your problem?

Comment: yes, when I remove the condition in the if() statement, it works.

Answer (score 0):

What about removing the `+` sign?

Just use `yOffset = canvas.height / 6 - (this.y - yOffset)`

Comment: This didn't change it; I think the thing that happens after the if() statement doesn't change the problem.